# Scan website for repeating keywords and create an array of it

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I want to scan an website and filter out the most repeating keywords in the site.

If i would scan for example https://www.adidas.at/ then i would like to have an array with keywords like:

`["clothing", "shoes", "pants", "t-shirt"]`

and so on.

My idea was first to get all text content witch is inside of `<body>` with `$eval()` and split it up into an array and the use `.reduce()` and count how many times an word appears on the site and rank it.

Is this the way to go or is there an simple solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the best approach would be to use `page.evaluate()`, and inside, acquire `outerText` of body which would return all the text content without the tags and stuff. After which you can convert the entire text to lower case(using `toLowerCase()`), and split the string on whitespaces or linebreaks or certain other symbols like brackets, etc. You can them keep count of repeated words using an object to store key values of word-count. So in essence your code would look like this:

```
let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
  //acquire the text in body
  let content = document.querySelector("body").outerText;
  
  //convert text to lowercase and split on whitespaces and newlines
  let textArray = content.toLowerCase().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/gm, " ").split(/\s+/gm);

  //object to map text to count
  let text_to_count_map = {};

  textArray.forEach(t => {
    if(text_to_count_map[t])
       text_to_count_map[t] ++;
    else
       text_to_count_map[t] = 1;
  });

  return text_to_count_map;
})
```

Now your `data` variable will contain an object of each word in the body as the key whose corresponding value would be their frequency in the body. You can do with it whatever you wish.

**EDIT 1**

Tested this on the Adidas site, and able to acquire all the words in the body into an array for `textArray` variable.

**FINAL EDIT**

Used a simpler regexp to filter anything that is not containing letters (`[^A-Za-z0-9]`)

[image]

Comment: seems to work well. But i get `null` instead of the number. Note here i am using it in Node.js

Comment: Are you checking the `data` variable that you get back from `page.evaluate()`?

Comment: i found it already. You need to swap the `if else` statement in the foreach loop

Comment: yeah just made the edit. I made a logical oopsie. My bad

Comment: i added an extra filter. if `(t.length < 3) return ` to filter out words with max 2 chars

Comment: Check newer edit.It accounts for filtering out all special characters.

Comment: for clarity thats my programm https://blogxon.com/tools/discount-code-finder i want to add an input bar where you can search for shoes for example. before the filter i need to collect data from the website. thats the idea behind it